# A good open-source directory/org chart software

Tags: open-source, web-apps, google-apps, charts

I work in an organization with a headcount of 7,000+, which I joined ~3 months ago.  It is extremely difficult to contact, or to find contact details of the person one is looking for. The usual way here is for people to put their contact details in their e-mail signatures, and hopefully the person you want to talk to would have e-mailed you in the past.

We use Gmail and hangouts, but people often do not respond to hangouts. What I would want to do is the following -

1. Search for a person by name, and get his details. Conversely, search for people by phone numbers.
2. Given a person, I want to know what team he works in, what his team does, who he reports to, and who report to him, and his peers.
3. Should be bulk-update friendly - often many employees join as a batch, or people get promoted in batches.
4. It would be nice if there was a corresponding (Android) app for looking up/dialling people.

**Is there an open-source application which does this?**

I worked for Amazon many years ago - they had such a user directory that was pretty bare-bones, but user-friendly - looking for something similar to that.

Comment: If your firm hasn't published this information internally, then it (hopefully) won't be accessible using any given external tool. However as you may likely have common email system, the information is available and you need to go internally to the email server team and/or your superiors and ask them to formalise and publish this information. It is **not** your task as a working guy to build/generate a firms user directory.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it ask for software only. It is attracting downvotes because 'how-to' questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia Foundation made one, a bit sluggish and only tested for ~200 persons but sort of worked, [WikiMedia OrgChart](https://git.wikimedia.org/summary/wikimedia%2forgchart)

It looked like this, except it actually loaded the chart,

[image: Wikimedia Foundation Chart]